# can't record audio via volume up button

Tags: android, key, media, volume, recorder

im trying to create and app with a recording an audio and playing it. 
it currently has 2 buttons - 1 for recording and 1 for playing the last recorded sound.
when im pressing the recording button it works perfect.

then, i tried to make it record by capturing the volume up button click.(wanted to make it record as long as the button is pressed).

when i try to record from the volume up button it throws me and IllegalStateException.

this is how i handle the click action on the volume up:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
 switch(keyCode){
   case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
     player.startRecording();
     return true;
 }
 return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch(keyCode){
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
            player.stopRecording();
            return true;
        }

    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```

thx in advance and sorry for the bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you hold volume up button, it will fire **onKeyDown** event continuesly..in each such call it invokes **player.stopRecording()**;.. this may cause problem,,,just try below logic...

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

int keyStatus=0;//public variable, 0=key released,1=key pressed

//
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     switch(keyCode){
       case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
         //player.startRecording();
           if(keyStatus==0){
               keyStatus=1;//setting this to 1 to ensure that this block is called only once during the key pressed state
               Log.d("msg", "startRecording()");
           }
         return true;
     }
     return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
@Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        switch(keyCode){
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
               Log.d("msg", "stopRecording()");
               keyStatus=0;//reset keyStatus on key up event.
                return true;
            }

        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }

//
```

Comment: didn't know it keeps repeating the click if you hold it down. kinda strange if you ask me. anyways, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
        switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
            if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                //TODO
            }
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
            if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                //TODO
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
        }
    }
```